# question about B.N.F

Tags: math-software, formal-languages

for example i have a code of strings which is efzau and 47 how can i define a grammar, set of terminal symbols and set of non terminal using B.N.F?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing BNF stands for Backus-Naur Form.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form but I have no idea what efzau is.

Comment: It is just a string example that we need to generate in the B.N.F

Comment: Just define "efzau" and "47" as terminals and some start symbol to be either "efzau" or "47" and you're done.